# What can be the risks of opening mdb files in windows using microsoft access?

Tags: firefox

I have download file.mdb from internet. When I click to open it, firefox tells me that mdb is an executable file and can harm my computer! How can this file harm my computer and is it just for mdb files or excel and words

Comment: I don't think that you are interpreting the message correctly or you are missing some information. I just tested my Firefox and it does not warn on mdb files. Can you show the message? And was it Firefox showing the message? Was the file `file.mdb.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Firefox is telling you that ".mdb" files can harm your computer, but rather Microsoft Access is telling you this warning message.  A ".mdb" file is a MS Access 2007 and earlier type of Access database file.  Every file that is downloaded from the internet and opened by any MS Office application will give a warning when opening the file.

The reason being that, in many MS Office applications you can insert something called "macros" in an MS Office file.  Macros are short programs that are written usually in VB Script (Visual Basic), and their intended purpose is to do minute tasks.  Since malicious software can also be created from VB, it is possible for a macro in an MS Office file to be malicious code.

For a user that will be using the macros for themselves later, it would not be concern as they themselves were the original creators of the macros.  However, trouble comes when opening files from the internet, as the file may contain malicious macros that may infect the computer.  Thus, the reason why such warning messages come when opening MS Office files from the internet, with a MS Office application.